# Проблема в подстановке параметров в запросе к API с бекенда. (Retrofit, Ktor, android)

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, ktor

Возникла проблема в подстановке параметров в запросе к API с бекенда. (Когда подставляю в URL вручную - все работает, но если с помощью @Query - то нет.)

Метод в приложении:

```
 @GET("notes") 
 suspend fun fetchDiaryNotes(
     @Query("from") from: Int,
     @Query("pageSize") pageSize: Int
 ) : List<DiaryNoteDto>
```

Метод на бекенде (Ktor):

```
fun Route.notes() {
    get("/notes/{from}/{pagesize}") {
        val from = call.parameters["from"]
        val pagesize = call.parameters["pagesize"]
        if (from != null && pagesize != null) {
            call.respond(
                HttpStatusCode.OK,
                notes.filter { note ->
                    note.id in from.toInt() until from.toInt() + pagesize.toInt()
                }
            )
        } else {
            call.respond(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Параметры запроса были пустыми")
        }
    }
}
```

В логах андроид приложения:

```
Process: space.rodionov.template_for_practice, PID: 4899
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 652736636 byte allocation with 1723604 free bytes and 381MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
```

В логах бекенда:

```
2022-01-05 22:21:27.818 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] INFO  Application - 404 Not Found: GET - /notes
```

При этом нормально срабатывает и возвращает список если вручную запихиваю параметры в URL при запросе из приложения:

```
@GET("notes/1/5")
suspend fun fetchDiaryNotes() : List<DiaryNoteDto> // вот так работает нормально.
```

Вопрос: что я неправильно делаю в подстановке параметров запроса в запрос? Где ошибка (в коде бекенда или приложения)?

Comment: Query это `notes?from=1&pageSize=5` получается. Пользуйтесь Log Interceptor чтобы видеть что реально уходит на сервер из Retrofit. https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@GET("notes/1/5")` - здесь нет query, это **path**
Оформляется немного по-другому:

```kotlin
 @GET("notes/{from}/{pageSize}") 
 suspend fun fetchDiaryNotes(
     @Path("from") from: Int,
     @Path("pageSize") pageSize: Int
 ) : List<DiaryNoteDto>
```